# Imported Invoices not Getting Customer Data

Tags: quickbooks

I am really new to Quickbooks.

I have created a program that creates an IIF file, which includes the customers to import, vendors, custom fields, and transactions to be added.

The import works great with the exception that when I open an invoice the customer address, is blank. I am not passing this address through the TRNS line because I am asssuming Quickbooks will link to the appropriate customer and fill it in for me.

```
!HDR    PROD    VER REL IIFVER  DATE    TIME    ACCNTNT ACCNTNTSPLITTIME
HDR QuickBooks Premier  Version 23.0D   Release R11P    1   2014-01-12  1389549203  N   0
!CUSTNAMEDICT   INDEX   LABEL   CUSTOMER    VENDOR  EMPLOYEE
!ENDCUSTNAMEDICT
CUSTNAMEDICT    0   Customer Number Y   N   N
ENDCUSTNAMEDICT
!CUST   NAME    REFNUM  TIMESTAMP   BADDR1  BADDR2  BADDR3  BADDR4  BADDR5  SADDR1  SADDR2  SADDR3  SADDR4  SADDR5  PHONE1  PHONE2  FAXNUM  EMAIL   NOTE    CONT1   CONT2   CTYPE   TERMS   TAXABLE SALESTAXCODE    LIMIT   RESALENUM   REP TAXITEM NOTEPAD SALUTATION  COMPANYNAME FIRSTNAME   MIDINIT LASTNAME    CUSTFLD1    CUSTFLD2    CUSTFLD3    CUSTFLD4    CUSTFLD5    CUSTFLD6    CUSTFLD7    CUSTFLD8    CUSTFLD9    CUSTFLD10   CUSTFLD11   CUSTFLD12   CUSTFLD13   CUSTFLD14   CUSTFLD15   JOBDESC JOBTYPE JOBSTATUS   JOBSTART    JOBPROJEND  JOBEND  HIDDEN  DELCOUNT    PRICELEVEL
CUST    Acdi    450 13.09.34    Acdi    Accounts Payable    5350 Partner's Court    Frederick, Md 21703                         301-624-1615        301-624-1683    Bheinrich@acdi.Com  450-PAT Brenda Heinrich         N30 N                               Acdi                450                                                                 0               N   0
CUST    Leidos - Ap 5765    13.09.34    Leidos - Ap Mail Stop 2113-03g  P O Box 2501    Oak Ridge, Tn 37831                         410-312-2226        410-312-2053    Sarah.L.Hudson@saic.Com 5765-SAI    Sarah Hudson            N30 N                               Leidos - Ap             5765                                                                    0               N   0
CUST    Rockwell Collins    5905    13.09.34    Rockwell Collins    400 Collins Rd Ne   M/s 124-204 Cedar Rapids, Ia 52498                          972-705-1725        972-705-1526    Fepresto@rockwellcollins.Com    5905-RCT    Fred Preston            N30 N                               Rockwell Collins                5905                                                                    0               N   0
CUST    Byk-Gardner Usa 6080    13.09.34    Byk-Gardner Usa 9104 Guilford Road  Columbia, Md 21046                              301-483-6500        301-483-6555    Larry.Kuehner@altana.Com    6080-BYK    Larry Kuehner           N30 N                               Byk-Gardner Usa             6080                                                                    0               N   0
CUST    Imt, Llc    6550    13.09.34    Imt, Llc    200 International Dr    Suite 1 Budd Lake, Nj 07828                         908-852-3700        908-852-9182    Maria.Gamble@vitecgroup.Com 6550-NCI    Maria Gamble            N30 N                               Imt, Llc                6550                                                                    0               N   0
!VEND   NAME    REFNUM  TIMESTAMP   PRINTAS ADDR1   ADDR2   ADDR3   ADDR4   ADDR5   VTYPE   CONT1   CONT2   PHONE1  PHONE2  FAXNUM  EMAIL   NOTE    TAXID   LIMIT   TERMS   NOTEPAD SALUTATION  COMPANYNAME FIRSTNAME   MIDINIT LASTNAME    CUSTFLD1    CUSTFLD2    CUSTFLD3    CUSTFLD4    CUSTFLD5    CUSTFLD6    CUSTFLD7    CUSTFLD8    CUSTFLD9    CUSTFLD10   CUSTFLD11   CUSTFLD12   CUSTFLD13   CUSTFLD14   CUSTFLD15   1099    HIDDEN  DELCOUNT
VEND    City Of Hagerstown  9680    13.09.34    City Of Hagerstown  City Of Hagerstown  Automated Speed Enforceme   P O Box 5046    Hagerstown, Md 217415046        VTYPE           000-000-0000                                        City Of Hagerstown                                                                          N   N   0
VEND    Thompson Services   9685    13.09.34    Thompson Services   Thompson Services   6708 Old National Pike  P O Box 158 Boonsboro, Md 21713     VTYPE           000-000-0000                                        Thompson Services                                                                           N   N   0
VEND    Espe Manufacturing Co   9690    13.09.34    Espe Manufacturing Co   Espe Manufacturing Co   9220 Ivanhoe Street Schiller Park, Il 60176         VTYPE           000-000-0000                                        Espe Manufacturing Co                                                                           N   N   0
VEND    Island Nameplate Inc    9695    13.09.34    Island Nameplate Inc    Island Nameplate Inc    124 South Main St   Florida, Ny 10921           VTYPE           000-000-0000                                        Island Nameplate Inc                                                                            N   N   0
VEND    Discus  9700    13.09.34    Discus  Discus  829 Bethel Road Suite 105   Columbus, Oh 43214      VTYPE           000-000-0000                                        Discus                                                                          N   N   0
!TRNS   TRNSID  TRNSTYPE    DATE    ACCNT   NAME    CLASS   AMOUNT  DOCNUM  MEMO    CLEAR   TOPRINT NAMEISTAXABLE   ADDR1   ADDR2   ADDR3   ADDR4   ADDR5   DUEDATE TERMS   PAID    SHIPVIA SHIPDATE     OTHER1 REP FOB PONUM   INVTITLE    INVMEMO SADDR1  SADDR2  SADDR3  SADDR4  SADDR5  PAYITME YEARTODATE  WAGEBASE    EXTRA   TOSEND  ISAJE
!SPL    SPLID   TRNSTYPE    DATE    ACCNT   NAME    CLASS   AMOUNT  DOCNUM  MEMO    CLEAR   QNTY    PRICE   INVITEM PAYMETH TAXABLE VALADJ  REIMBEXP    SERVICEDATE OTHER2  OTHER3  PAYITEM YEARTODATE  WAGEBASE    EXTRA
!ENDTRNS
TRNS    24899   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Accounts Receivable Imt, Llc             1106.25        Test        Y   N   Imt, Llc    200 International Dr    Suite 1 Budd Lake, NJ 07828         N30     UPS 1/14/2014           Frederick   380298/1            Imt, Llc    200 International Drive Suite 1 Budd Lake, NJ 07828                         
SPL 24899   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Imt, Llc        -1106.25        712-00024-00a-R-X2      -25 44.25   Drawing     N                                   
SPL                                 Shipping Ticket # 85497                                                         
ENDTRNS
TRNS    24733   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Accounts Receivable Byk-Gardner Usa           581.90        Test        Y   N   Byk-Gardner Usa 9104 Guilford Road  Columbia, MD 21046              N30     UPS 1/14/2014           Frederick   4500435362          Byk-Gardner Usa     9104 Guilford Road  Columbia, MD 210462729                              
SPL 24733   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Byk-Gardner Usa     -581.90     025c210-03-A        -11 52.90   Drawing     N                                   
SPL                                 Shipping Ticket # 85498                                                         
ENDTRNS
TRNS    24201   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Accounts Receivable Rockwell Collins              794.20        Test        Y   N   Rockwell Collins    400 Collins Rd Ne   M/s 124-204 Cedar Rapids, IA 52498          N30     UPS 1/14/2014           Frederick   4505160857          Rockwell Collins    2855 Heartland Drive    Coralville, IA 52241                                
SPL 24201   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Rockwell Collins        -794.20     50820-01-B      -11 72.20   Drawing     N                                   
SPL                                 Shipping Ticket # 85501                                                         
ENDTRNS
TRNS    24833   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Accounts Receivable Leidos           1562.00        Test        Y   N   Leidos - Ap Mail Stop 2113-03g  P O Box 2501    Oak Ridge, TN 37831         N30     UPS 1/14/2014           Frederick   TA0424          Leidos  6500 Kane Way Suite J   Dock 9 Or 10    Elkridge, MD 21075                          
SPL 24833   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Leidos - Ap     -1142.00        Sa009261-A      -20 57.10   Drawing     N                                   
SPL 24833   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Leidos - Ap     -210.00     Sa009262-01--       -20 10.50   Drawing     N                                   
SPL 24833   INVOICE 1/14/2014   Sales - Hardware    Leidos - Ap     -210.00     Sa009262-02--       -20 10.50   Drawing     N                                   
SPL                                 Shipping Ticket # 85502                                                         
ENDTRNS
```

I have looked over the tutorial on the Quickbooks site and followed it and used the examples provided as well as searched the web for anything that could help and have came up pretty empty.

Am I doing something wrong or is Quickbooks working as designed and cannot sync an imported invoice with a customer?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but... IIF files have been *deprecated* by Intuit for almost 10 years now. *You should not be using IIF files*.

They are known to have bugs and cause company file corruption.

Have you looked at the [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/us)? It's a much better (and programming-oriented) solution to getting data into QuickBooks in an automated fashion.

If you say what programming language you're using, you'll get even better, more detailed answers.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers this helps me out a lot. I am using RPG to create this file I will have a look at the SDK to see if it can be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

First to let you know, the IIF file format is an outdated format that is no longer supported by Intuit. While QuickBooks can still import these files, they can cause data damage as they allow invalid data into the database.

That being said, this is a limitation of the IIF import. If you do not specify the field values on the transaction line, it will not use the defaults, even if the customer record has them.